# Borrar fila de la base de datos phpmyadmin me da el siguiente error:

Tags: java, mysql

```
   public void bajaCliente(){

    Connection miConexion;

    Statement st;

    try {    

    miConexion=DriverManager.getConnection

    ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fastfoodcompany", "root", 
   "quepasachavales3");

        st=miConexion.createStatement();


        String query="DELETE FROM clientes WHERE  Nombre, Appelido1, Apellido2 = '"+ Nombre +"'" + " '"+ Apellido1 +"'" + " '"+ Apellido2 +"'";


        Nombre=panelaltaclientes.getTxtNombre().getText();
        Apellido1=panelaltaclientes.getTxtApellido1().getText();
        Apellido2=panelaltaclientes.getTxtApellido2().getText();

        st.executeUpdate(query);


        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "El cliente ha sido dado de baja correctamente");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(bdFFC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "El cliente no ha sido dado de baja"+ex);
    }

}
```

Lo que me pasa es que este metodo bajaCliente al ejecutarlo en mi JFrame pretando al boton de dar de baja me sale el siguiente error:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' Appelido1, Apellido2 = 'null' 'null' 'null'' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los valores de cada variable en sentencias SQL se asignan a cada variable en particular. Estas escribiendo el nombre de las tres columnas y a continuación de las tres sus correspondientes valores, cuando en realidad el valor se especifica después del nombre de cada columna. Sería algo así:

```
public void bajaCliente(){

    Connection miConexion;
    Statement st;

    try {    

       miConexion=DriverManager.getConnection(
       "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fastfoodcompany", "root", "quepasachavales3");
       st=miConexion.createStatement();
       String query="DELETE FROM clientes WHERE  Nombre = '" + Nombre + "', Appelido1= '" + Apellido1 + "', Apellido2 = '" + Apellido2 +"'";

       Nombre=panelaltaclientes.getTxtNombre().getText();
       Apellido1=panelaltaclientes.getTxtApellido1().getText();
       Apellido2=panelaltaclientes.getTxtApellido2().getText();

       st.executeUpdate(query);

       JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "El cliente ha sido dado de baja correctamente");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(bdFFC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "El cliente no ha sido dado de baja"+ex);
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Tu query es totalmente erronea. Los campos van en clave=valor, no clave1, clave2, clave3 = Valor1, Valor2, Valor3 ...

Cambiala por esto.

```
String query="DELETE FROM clientes WHERE  Nombre= '"+ Nombre +"' AND Apellido1 = '"+ Apellido1 +"' AND Apellido2 = '"+ Apellido2 +"'";
```

Aparte creo que este bloque deberia ir antes de la query si recojes los valores aquí.

```
Nombre=panelaltaclientes.getTxtNombre().getText();
Apellido1=panelaltaclientes.getTxtApellido1().getText();
Apellido2=panelaltaclientes.getTxtApellido2().getText();
```

Por ultimo, tu query es muy vulnerable a inyección SQL,  deberías usar sentencias preparadas.

PD: Los nombres de las variables por norma deberían ir en CamelCase con la primera letra en minuscula.

PD2: PhpMyAdmin no es una base de datos, es un software para trabajar con la base de datos MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias funciona correctamente, he seguido tus consejos lo siento por expresarme tan mal pero estoy empezando a programar.
Un saludo y gracias de nuevo.